# Sharepoint List data format

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I am getting a list stored in sharepoint 2013 using rest api successfully. On the client side i want to iterate through the object. Can anybody tell me how the data is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each list item as follows:

```
 function (data) 
    {  
      if (data.d != undefined)
      {
      //Check if the list has data
      if (data.d.results.length > 0)
      {       
      //Iterate through each items fetched from the list
     $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item)
       {

        var fieldVal= item.fieldName;
});
}
}
}
```

You can see the response format in the browser for your list by using the following url:

**site url + /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items**

Refer the following url for more info:
http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/sharepoint-2013-rest-odata-part-1-readingfetching-information-no-code/

Comment: yes i got it sometimeback. Thanks. Also i would like to add, my field name was "DisplayName" and it did not show up in data.d.results[index].DisplayName. Changing it to ReportsName did the trick. I am not sure why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It can be either XML or JSON.

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

> The following code demonstrates how this request would look if you are
>   using the cross-domain library and want to receive the OData
>   representation of the lists as XML instead of JSON. See How to: Access
>   SharePoint 2013 data from apps using the cross-domain library for more
>   information about using the cross-domain library.

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I am able to recieve the json. I want to know the structure of the JSON to iterate through each list item.